# Primal Dual model in the continuous domain

Tags: ds.algorithms, max-flow-min-cut, primal-dual

The continuous max flow problem is posed as follows :

sup $\int_\Omega  p_s(x)dx$

subject to :

$|p(x)| \le C(x);  \forall x \in \Omega $

$p_s(x) \le C_s(x);  \forall x \in \Omega $

$p_t(x) \le C_t(x);  \forall x \in \Omega $

$\nabla \cdot p(x) - p_s(x) + p_t(x) = 0;  \forall x \in \Omega $

Here $p(x)$ is a field vector and is analogous to the flow in the discrete domain. $\nabla \cdot p$ is the divergence of the field p.

How do i find out the dual of this maximization problem using the lagrangian dual technique, i.e. the equivalent min cut formulation of the problem in the continuous domain.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your question may be answered in the following paper:

@article{strang1983maximal,
  title={Maximal flow through a domain},
  author={Strang, G.},
  journal={Mathematical Programming},
  volume={26},
  number={2},
  pages={123--143},
  year={1983},
  publisher={Springer}
}

Comment: The paper does not take the approach that i want to follow. I believe that the dual can be obtained by simply finding the lagrangian function. I just did not know how to find the lagrangian dual function for the given function. I have now worked it out.